# Wordpress/ACF Image Field HTTPS/SSL

Tags: wordpress, image, ssl, https, advanced-custom-fields

When using the “image” type custom field, and also having a Return Value of “Image URL”, and then in my template using `<img src="<?php the_field('mycustomimage'); ?>">`, it’s returning an http URL instead of an https URL, causing mixed content on my site. Other areas of the site are returning an https URL, like when I use `wp_get_attachment_image_src();` for example.

How do I get it to return an https URL?

Answer (score 0):

There's a variety of [Insecure Content Fixing](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/) plugins out there, as well as [Simple SSL Setup](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/) plugins that work well. There's also some documentation in the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL) that may help.

If neither of those fix your issue, you can simply do a string replace on the returned values. Note you may want to instead use the returning `get_` functions instead of the echoing `the_` functions for ease of use:

```
<img src="<?= str_replace( 'http://', 'https://', get_field( 'mycustomimage' ) ); ?>">
```

Also make sure your site is set to `https://` in your General Settings if its not already

**Edit:**

In regards to your comment: Was the admin secured with `https://` when the images were uploaded? Also the insecure content fixer and simple ssl setup plugins should effectively just require activation (or network activate) and basically be good to go.

If those don't work, you've modified all DB records, and everything *should* be working, you could always do a runtime find and replace, while it's a bit hacky, I have actually used code similar to this for a similar purpose before when some things just "stuck" to an old protocol despite everything saying they should be updated to a new one.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() use($startTime){
    ob_start( function( $buffer ){
        if( is_ssl() ) $buffer = str_ireplace( 'src="http://', 'src="https://', $buffer );

        return $buffer;
    });
});
```

Note that this will require anything with a `src` attribute to have an appropriately SSL'd resource, including external resources (iframes, scripts, etc.) - otherwise you'll need to complicate it a bit with `preg_replace_callback()` and some regular expressions to only grab `img` tags.

Comment: Is there not a way to do this globally? I'm working on a large site and I have code like this in a lot of places. Also, I have already done a search and replace in the database to change http to https but it still doesn't seem to be changing them. I used [this](https://blog.templatetoaster.com/update-old-urls-in-database/) as a guide.

Comment: Updated the answer